# SQLite Database not created using python code

Tags: database, sqlite

Quite new to coding, I am stuck with this code.It prints out the counts in the command terminal but doesn't create the database file in SQLite. The sqlite version I am using is 3.10.1

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts''')

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'abc.txt'
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if not (line.startswith('From: ')) : continue
    pieces = line.split()
    org = pieces[1].split('@')[1]
    print org
    cur.execute('''SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE org = ? ''', (org, ))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Counts (org, count) VALUES ( ?, 1 )''', ( org, ) )
    else : 
        cur.execute('''UPDATE Counts SET count=count+1 WHERE org = ?''', 
        (org, ))
# This statement commits outstanding changes to disk each 
# time through the loop - the program can be made faster 
# by moving the commit so it runs only after the loop completes
conn.commit()


sqlstr = '''SELECT org, count FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10'''

print "Counts:"
for row in cur.execute(sqlstr) :
    print str(row[0]), row[1]

cur.close()
```

Comment: I suggest you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for the sqlite3 lib.

Comment: Works for me. Show how you execute it and how you look for the DB file.